# Better way to write ngClass condition

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to think of a cleaner way to write this condition:

```
    [ngClass]="{
      'class1':
        image.isAvailable && (image.property !== true && !null),
      'class2':
        image.isAvailable && (image.property === true && !null)
    }"
```

So image.property sometimes can be NULL, and I am trying to handle it...I know I'm missing something obvious but don't know what. Any help much appreciated

Comment: You can use the ternary operator .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use safe navigation operator `?.` with ternary operator.

```js
[ngClass]="(image?.isAvailable && image?.property) ? 'class1' : 'class2'"
```

Safe navigation operator checks if a property is defined before trying to access it.

#### Update

OP's requirement - use neither of the classes if `image?.isAvailable` is undefined.

You could extend the ternary operator to one more level to check if `image?.isAvailable` is defined before applying the classes.

```js
[ngClass]="image?.isAvailable ? (image?.property ? 'class1' : 'class2') : ''"
```

The empty string `''` denotes empty class list if `image?.isAvailable` property is undefined.

Comment: thanks, this would take care of that Null if it occurs then?

Comment: Yes, `null` is falsy. So it would take care if the property is `null` or even if the property is undefined.

Comment: hm... the thing is, I don't want any of the two classes if !image?.isAvailable, what I am trying to achieve is: if image is available and also has image.property true, set class1. If image is available and also has image.property false, set other class... If image?.isAvailable is false, dont' show any of the two classes. Maybe I got confused, but would this be the case?

Comment: @Smithy: You could just extend the ternary operator. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you this has really helped me!

Answer (score 0):

This can be written like this:

```
[ngClass]="{
      'class1':
        image.isAvailable && !image.property),
      'class2':
        image.isAvailable && image.property)
    }"
```

Also you can write like this:

```
[class.class1]="image.isAvailable && !image.property"
[class.class2]="image.isAvailable && image.property"
```